# Repeating Command in Excel Macro over 28118 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have been dealing with larger and larger spreadsheets and have recently began experimenting with macros. Unfortunately, I am still very much a beginner and cannot figure out how to loop or simply repeat 2556 times what is a very simple task in excel.

I have 2556 (15x2) tables of data spread over 28118 rows in a spreadsheet and I want to cut and paste specific cells (located in a row between each table) into the table itself (2556 times). I have the following macro:

```
Sub stat_shr()
'
' Shr_Ma Macro
' H6 stats Sorting xls
'

'
    Range("B7").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B18").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A24").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B29").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A35").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I would like to repeat this task over the range of 28118 rows, instead of what is shown above. To be more precise, I would need to begin by moving cell B7->A13, B18->A24, B29->A35 and so on, repeating this until moving B28013 -> A28019. The relevant cells in columns A and B are separated by 10 (not blank) rows. Could someone provide some help with this?

Comment: so you want to move each 11th cell? i.e. B7->A13, B18->A24,...?

Comment: Not sure what's the logic behind cutting those cells. At first I thought it's 6 rows below and 1 column to the left, but A24 -> B29 does not match.

Comment: @simoco , yes, each 11th cell 6 rows down and 1 column to the left.

Comment: @lowak that is exactly what I want to do, perhaps my description was not very clear, I have now corrected this.

Comment: Not really, you did right I just looked in a wrong place and misread your code. I think ForteDevelop wrote a code of your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop with a step. It will increase the variable by whatever number you enter:

```
for row = 7 to 28013 step 11
    Range("B" & row).cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A" & row + 6)
next row
```

You might have to adjust the numbers here, but this should be basically what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need a For... Next loop. First, determine how many times the cut and paste operation needs to happen. Say it is 100 times, then:

```
For i = 0 to 99
    cells(7+i*11,2).cut
    activesheet.paste destination:=cells(13+i*11,1)
Next
```

Note that you don't need to "Select" cells or ranges to work with them. In fact, it is hardly ever necessary to use "Select" - that's just the way the macro recorder works.